# OutOfDirectMemoryError using Spring-Data-Redis with Lettuce in a multi-threading context

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

We are using `spring-data-redis` with the `spring-cache` abstraction and `lettuce` as our redis-client.
Additionally we use multi-threading and async execution on some methods.

**An example workflow would look like this:**

Main-Method A (main-thread)  --> calls Method B (`@Async`) which is a proxy-method to be able to run the logic asynchronously in another thread. --> Method B calls Method C, which is `@Cacheable`. The `@Cacheable` Annotation handles reading/writing to our redis-cache.

**What's the problem?**

`Lettuce` is `Netty`-based which works relying on the `DirectMemory`. Due to the `@Async` nature of our program, we have multiple threads using the `LettuceConnection` (and therefore `Netty`) at the same time.

By design all threads will use the same (?) `Netty` which shares the `DirectMemory`. Due to an apparently too small `MaxDirectMemorySize` we get an `OutOfDirectMemoryError`, when too many threads are accessing `Netty`.

Example:
`io.lettuce.core.RedisException: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 8388352 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 4746467, max: 10485760)`

**What have we found so far?**

We use the https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/ and calculate the `MaxDirectMemorySize` using the https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-memory-calculator.

Which leeds to a `MaxDirectMemorySize=10M`. Having an actual available memory of 4GB the calculated `MaxDirectMemorySize` is probably way to conservative. This might be part of the problem.

**Potential solutions to the problem**

- increase the `MaxDirectMemorySize` of the JVM --> but we are not sure that is sufficent
- configure `Netty` not to use the `DirectMemory` (`noPreferDirect=true`) --> `Netty` will then use the heap, but we are insecure if this would slow down our application too much if `Netty` is too hungry for memory
- no idea if this would be an option or even make the problem worse: configure `Lettuce` to `shareNativeConnection=false` --> which would lead to multiple connections to the redis

**Our Question is: How do we solve this the correct way?**

I'll happily provide more information on how we set up the configuration of our application (application.yml, LettuceConnection etc.), if any of these would help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the folks over at: https://gitter.im/lettuce-io/Lobby we got some clues on how to approach these issues.

As suspected, the 10M `MaxDirectMemorySize` is too conservative considering the total available memory.

Recommendation was to increase this value. Since we don't actually know how much memory `Netty` would need to perform more stable, we thought of the following steps.

**First:** We will disable `Netty`'s preference of the `MaxDirectMemory` by setting `noPreferDirect=true`. `Netty` will then use the heap-buffer.

**Second:** We will then monitor how much heap-memory `Netty` is going to consume during operation. Doing this, we'll be able to infer an average memory consumption for `Netty`.

**Third:** We will take the average memory consumption value and set this as the "new" `MaxDirectMemorySize` by setting it in the JVM option `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize`. Then we'll re-enable `Netty` to use the `DirectMemory` by setting `noPreferDirect=false`.

**Fourth:** Monitor log-entries and exceptions and see if we still have a problem or if this did the trick.

**[UPDATE]**
We started with the mentioned steps but realized, that setting `noPreferDirect=true` does not completely deter netty from using DirectMemory. For some use-cases (nio-Processes) `Netty` still uses DirectMemory.

So we had to increase the `MaxDirectMemorySize`.

For now we set the following JAVA_OPTS `-Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=true -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=100M`. Which will probably fix our issue.

Comment: Hi @Sidekick_John I have tried the same steps as you said. We have increased the XX:MaxDirectMemorySize to 20GB, but still after some time we are getting this exception. did you happen to fix this issue anyhow. Kindly share your experience.